# Creating a Norton Bootable Recovery Tool from within Norton Internet Security (2013)?

Tags: bootable-media, norton-internet-security

I have heard rumours that I can create a Norton Bootable Recovery Tool straight from within my Norton Internet Security 2013 interface/settings. Does anyone have experience in creating this & provide appropriate guidance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that the recovery tool is available on the product cd that your Norton install came on if you have that and its also readily available for download. See here [Norton Recovery Tools](http://security.symantec.com/nbrt/overview.aspx?ssdcat=221&lcid=1033&origin=techsup&env=prod&layout=esd&tooltype=nbrt).

I have not heard of or have experience with making a bootable device straight from Norton but maybe someone else has

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I dont have a product cd as I didnt buy a boxed version of the software. However thanx for providing the link above - it looks promising